# Unity Nav mesh lading data each frame

Tags: unity, performance, navmesh

Hey all I had a question, I was looking into my game's performance and noticed this in the profiler:

[image: Peformance capture]

Is there any way to optimize this such as pre-generating tiles so it doesn't have to do it each update :) ?

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? What would we need to put into a new, empty project in order to reproduce the navmesh update cost you're observing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your profiler hierarchy includes this entry:

```
Carving.ApplyResults
```

[Carving](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html) is an optional feature where non-static obstacles can cut a hole into the NavMesh. Carving is expensive because it actually modifies the NavMesh, which is why Unity recommends only enabling Carving while an object is not moving.

If you have a moving `NavMeshObstacle` with Carving enabled and "Carve Only Stationary" *unchecked*, it's going to be carving and rebuilding part of the Nav Mesh frequently as it moves around (possibly every frame if the Move Threshold is low). That could explain the entries you're seeing in the profiler.